# rclpy: Change the output format of the default logger (RcutilsLogger)

Tags: ros, logging, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My log messages look like:

> [INFO] [1605205588.116214862] [path_to_node.subsystem_name.node_name]: Here is a log message

The bit before the actual message takes up too much horizontal space, making it hard to read in my console (I'm using terminator, and have other consoles within it). I have already tried reducing the font size, but it still rarely fits on one line.

Could I change it so it is more like:

> [INFO] [node_name]: Here is a log message

Or even:

> [INFO]: Here is a log message

As often I do not care where the log message has come from.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365476/rclpy:-change-the-output-format-of-the-default-logger-(rcutilslogger)/) by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2020-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out.

I just need to set an eninonment variable, i.e type:

> export RCUTILS_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FORMAT="[{severity}]: {message}"

Into the console, I am running the node from.

http://docs.ros2.org/bouncy/api/rcutils/logging_8h.html#a27340ac73188b1cf8d9cb96d86c76694

---

Originally posted by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) with karma: 128 on 2020-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0